# Should I delete my unanswered question(s) that I've found but forgotten the answer to?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Recently, I received the warning that several of my recent questions haven't been well received. It seems that one cause for this warning is because of a high amount of deleted questions, and that undeleting questions can help remove the warning. As such, I undeleted all 5 of my (previously) deleted posts. I've answered one of them myself as I found the solution to the question a while ago, but I'm unsure of what to do about the following four questions.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603551/arithmetic-on-pointer-to-interface-id-which-is-not-a-constant-size-for-this-a): I fixed this error but I completely forgot what I did to resolve the problem.

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626373/invalid-operands-to-binary-expression-nsuinteger-aka-unsigned-long-an): This was an extremely localized question which was unlikely to help anyone either way. I fixed this error in this case with help from the comments but it sparked another error in another part of the application. I encouraged the commenter to post their comment as an answer so I could accept it (because it technically fixed the error I stated in my question). Is that my only course of action in this case? **I've now deleted the question. Here's a [picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKmDx.jpg) before it was deleted for the benefit of lower-rep users.**

[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524494/using-timestamps-to-find-elapsed-time-between-the-end-of-one-array-and-the-start): I solved this problem but the solution I used would only make sense in the context of my application and thus really isn't applicable at all to any other developer.

[Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366571/how-to-install-gpuimage-framework): Same as Question 1. I fixed the error but don't remember the exact course of action I took to fix it.

What should I do with these four questions? Delete/Close them? Answer them myself? Edit them to clarify? Also, if the recommended course of action is to delete the questions, is there a way I can do so without triggering the warning again?

Comment: Wait.... Deleted questions don't count MORE against the ban/warning than non deleted ones... Unless they have answers.....

Comment: @Patrice all of the question I linked to are unanswered and I don't have many recent downvoted posts. Is there another reason I'm receiving the question warning?

Comment: well... The actual record of all your questions isn't really positive. That is more likely to be an issue than anything else

Comment: I mean.. Out of 16 questions, 12 at 0, 3 negative, one positive... A net negative score. THIS is the issue.

Comment: @Patrice I agree, but two of those negative questions were asked nearly a year ago. Only one question was recently asked with a score of -1. Surely one downvoted answer isn't enough to trigger this warning.

Comment: well one Q might not be enough... But you have more than 1 Q there. The warning and ban look at all your previous content, so I guess you were one downvote away from the warning(and btw thanks for not flipping out. i do intend these to try to help you understand the warnings... Feels good to not get lashed at for once :p)

Comment: @Patrice I think I'll delete my second question. It really doesn't seem to have any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the warning today because [the question you asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626373/invalid-operands-to-binary-expression-nsuinteger-aka-unsigned-long-an) was downvoted.

That's it.

Now, that's not to say you shouldn't go back and answer older questions if you can - it's always nice to [leave artifacts for those who might later follow your trail](https://xkcd.com/979/) - but that's not *directly* what you're being warned about, nor do your deleted questions matter (with the exception of the ones that were downvoted, which matter because they were downvoted).

As always, the more you do to make your participation on the site useful to others, the more the system will consider you a useful contributor.